# how can I save (and read) contents of a JTable to a file?

Tags: java, file, io, jtable

relatively self explanatory, I have a `JTable (table)` and the `DefaultTableModel (model)`. I would like to save the contents of the **JTable** to a file, then read them into the **JTable** at a later time. How can i do this?

More Details: the JTable contains short strings, and there shouldn't be more than, say 50KB of data toal.

Comment: If the amount of persisted data is relatively small, there are tons of serialization libraries...just do a little investigative work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DefaultTableModel` implements Serializable. So the simplest solution would be to use an `ObjectOutputStream` and to call `writeObject()` with your model.

**Note:** Remember that objects which are hold by the `DefaultDataModel` needs to be `Serialazable`

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm There are a couple of factors on that decision. Mainly how big the data are, and how often the data are going to be read/write

Some ideas that pop into my head are to store the data into 
1- XML files
the simplest way to do that is to use the built in dom

http://www.roseindia.net/xml/dom/

2- database
I personally favour mysql. Its failry easy to use.Java offers a great set of sql functions
http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/java/
http://zetcode.com/databases/mysqljavatutorial/

If you have a huge set of data, or you need to randomly access elements in your table, then there are more to consider than these simple solutions

Regards